# to simplify mysql query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Exist database with data and many complicated tables. Main table is locations. it has one restaurant, restaurant has many cuisines and has one city, city has one state.
I have to write query what searching data from many field at several tables. 
My query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 locations.*
 FROM
 locations,
 restaurants,
 cities,
 states,
 cuisines
 WHERE
 locations.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
 AND locations.city_id = cities.id
 AND cities.state_id = states.id
 AND cuisines.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
 AND (
 restaurants.name LIKE '%miami%'
 OR cities.city LIKE '%miami%'
 OR cities.zip LIKE '%miami%'
 OR states.state LIKE '%miami%'
 OR states.state_code LIKE '%miami%'
 ) AND (restaurants.delivery_type = '1' OR restaurants.delivery_type = 0)
 AND (cuisines.`name` LIKE '%Japanese%')
```

I think is not good way. Please, help to simplify this query.

Comment: try this one..SELECT DISTINCT
 locations.*
 FROM locations,
 inner join restaurants on  locations.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
 inner join cities on locations.city_id = cities.id
 inner join states on cities.state_id = states.id
 inner join cuisines on cuisines.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
 WHERE
 (
 restaurants.name LIKE '%miami%'
 OR cities.city LIKE '%miami%'
 OR cities.zip LIKE '%miami%'
 OR states.state LIKE '%miami%'
 OR states.state_code LIKE '%miami%'
 ) AND (restaurants.delivery_type = '1' OR restaurants.delivery_type = 0)
 AND (cuisines.`name` LIKE '%Japanese%')

Comment: This is off-topic. Try posting it here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that because of the wildcard at the start of the string, this query cannot use indexes, so it will be inefficient...

```
 SELECT l.*
   FROM locations l
   JOIN restaurants r
     ON r.id = l.restaurant_id 
   JOIN cities c
     ON c.id = l.city_id
   JOIN states s
     ON s.id = c.state_id 
   JOIN cuisines u
     ON u.restaurant_id = r.id
  WHERE 
      ( r.name LIKE '%miami%'
     OR c.city LIKE '%miami%'
     OR c.zip LIKE '%miami%'
     OR s.state LIKE '%miami%'
     OR s.state_code LIKE '%miami%'
 )
    AND r.delivery_type IN(1,0)
    AND u.name LIKE '%Japanese%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "simplify" the query by writing it using table aliases and proper join syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.*
FROM locations l join
     restaurants r
     on l.restaurant_id = r.id join
     cities c
     on l.city_id = c.id join
     states s
     on c.state_id = s.id join
     cuisines cu
     on c.restaurant_id = r.id
WHERE (r.name LIKE '%miami%' OR
       c.city LIKE '%miami%' OR
       c.zip LIKE '%miami%' OR
       s.state LIKE '%miami%'
       s.state_code LIKE '%miami%'
      ) AND
      r.delivery_type in (0, 1) AND
      cu.`name` LIKE '%Japanese%';
```

The nature of this query makes it very difficult to optimize.  You are doing `like` with full wildcard searches.  If you are looking for names, then you should think about a full text index and using `match` instead of `like`.  This will also let you search multiple columns at the same time.  (Downside:  You can really only search for full words, so "Miami" would not match "Tamiami".)